# Show positive number with sign plus (chart axis)

Tags: reporting-services

How to show vertical axis of chart where sign of value is always presented.
Positive values should have sign '+' before the value and negative '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try an expression like the following:

```
=IIF(ABS(Fields!VerticalAxisField.Value) + Fields!VerticalAxisField.Value = 0, 
      "-", 
      "+") & Fields!VerticalAxisField.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply formatting the Axis labels.

Right-click the Axis you want to change and select 'properties'
Click 'Number' in the left options
Select 'Custom' and set the Custom Format to `+0;-0;0` will format he numbers as integers.

If you want to format with say, 1 decimal place, then just use something like `+0.0;-0.0;0`